# How to check multiple checkboxes with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes

```
<div class="data">    
    <span>
    <input name="employee" type="checkbox" value="Alex"/>
    <label for="employee">Alex</label>
    </span> 

    <span>
    <input name="employee" type="checkbox" value="Frank"/>
    <label for="employee">Frank</label>
    </span>    

    <span>
    <input name="employee" type="checkbox" value="Mark"/>
    <label for="employee">Mark</label>
    </span>
</div>
```

How to find all checked checkboxes and create json or array with result of checking?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In case you just want to use pure/vanilla JS, here is an example:

**HTML HEAD**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCheckedCheckboxesFor(checkboxName) {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="' + checkboxName + '"]:checked'), values = [];
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(checkboxes, function(el) {
        values.push(el.value);
    });
    return values;
}
</script>
```

**HTML BODY**

```
<div class="data">    
    <span>
    <input name="employee" type="checkbox" value="Alex"/>
    <label for="employee">Alex</label>
    </span> 

    <span>
    <input name="employee" type="checkbox" value="Frank"/>
    <label for="employee">Frank</label>
    </span>    

    <span>
    <input name="employee" type="checkbox" value="Mark"/>
    <label for="employee">Mark</label>
    </span>

    <input type="button" onclick="alert(getCheckedCheckboxesFor('employee'));" value="Get Values" />
</div>
```

JS Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/dY372/

Answer (score 8):

Try this:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7VfpZ/)

jQuery:

```
var selected = [];
$('.data input:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).val());
});
```

Javascript:

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('employee');
var selected = [];
for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        selected.push(checkboxes[i].value);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about if checkboxes are on pagination? How to check if its being checked?

Answer (score 2):

Using `querySelectorAll`:

```
var checked = document.querySelectorAll('[name="employee"]:checked');
```

Support: IE9+.

Answer (score 1):

```
var elements=document.getElementsByName('employee');
```

should return you an array of the elements you require

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cg79G/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function checked(){

    var items=getElementsByname('checkbox');

    var selectedlist=[];

    for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++)       
    {
        if(items[i].type=='checkbox' && items[i].checked==true)                 
            selectedlist+=items[i].value+"\n";
    }

    alert(selectedlist);
}
```