# How do include javascript to item checkbox so that the selected box calculates the price value automatucally?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, class, flexbox

Display four or more items to purchase along with their corresponding purchase price (use check boxes to allow selection of the items you wish to purchase). Give the checkboxes the name item_0, item_1, etc.
Include a Total field which automatically totals your purchases as each item is checked/unchecked or the specified quantity changes. Give this field the name total.

I need some help with this.

Here is the code of the simplest I have been able to do so far.

```
<h3> Cart </h3>
<input type = "checkbox" id = "item_0" name ="item_0" value = "Malt">
<label> Beta Malt </label>
<input type = "checkbox" id = "item_1" name ="item_1" value = "bread">
<label> A1 Bread </label>
<input type = "checkbox" id = "item_0" name ="item_2" value = "noodles">
<label> Indomie </label>
<input type = "checkbox" id = "item_0" name ="item_3" value = "milk">
<label> Cowbell </label>
```

Comment: That's html. Where's the javascript you tried? Where's the total element? Folks are willing to help, but most don't want to do your homework for you.

Comment: You should add the price somewhere, probably as the input's value. Then you can listen to the change event and do something with the values using event.target.value. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Answer (score 0):

First, change attributes name for the same.
You can use for example, [How to check multiple checkboxes with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175006/how-to-check-multiple-checkboxes-with-javascript).
Using this idea.

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="' + nameCheckbox + '"]:checked'), values = 0;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(checkboxes, function(el) {
        values += parseInt(el.value);
    });
```

alert(values);